# HttpPost Method not returning values

Tags: c#, post, odata

I have made below method. When I hit it from Advance rest client then I see below output but I dont see the values. While debugging, I can see the 3 records in lstPersonDetail of PersonDetail class type. Please tell is there anything I am missing?

Output:

```
{
    @odata.context: "http://localhost:9912/API-service/$metadata#System.Collections.Generic.List_1OfPersonDetail"
    Capacity: 4
}
```

Method:

```
[EnableQuery]
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("GetPersonDetails()")]
public List<PersonDetail> GetPersonDetails(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
    List<PersonDetail> lstPersonDetail = new List<PersonDetail>();
    if (parameters == null)
    {
        return lstPersonDetail;
    }

    IEnumerable<string> firstNames = parameters["firstNames"] as IEnumerable<string>;
    firstNames = firstNames.ToList();

    try
    {
        if (firstNames != null && firstNames.Count() > 0)
        {
            using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
            {
                lstPersonDetail = (from x in db.PersonData
                              from t in firstNames
                              where x.PersonFirstName.ToLower().Contains(t.ToLower())
                              select new PersonDetail
                              {
                                  FullName = x.FullName,
                                  City = x.City
                              }).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return lstPersonDetail;
}

public class PersonDetail
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using EnableQuery and ODataRoute?

Comment: But it will not impact flow of this method?, right?

Comment: What tooling you get your output in? Postman?

Comment: Not sure why you have these attributes. If you add things without reason they give you different results